# Group messaging mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, message

I'm following the following tutorial (scroll down to the bottom for the relevant part): http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/

My messages_helper.rb:

```
def recipients_options(chosen_recipient = nil)
  s = ''
  User.all.each do |user|
     s << "<option value='#{user.id}' data-img-src='#{gravatar_image_url(user.email, size: 50)}' #{'selected' if user == chosen_recipient}>#{user.name}</option>"
  end
  s.html_safe
end
```

My new.html.erb for the messages:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
  <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
def new
  @chosen_recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]
end
def create
   recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
   conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
   flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
   redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
end
```

Right now, this allows for one current recipient to be passed through a url like: **http://localhost:3000/messages/new?to=4**. But I want the ability to pass in multiple current users for a "group message", so a url like: **http://localhost:3000/messages/new?to=4&to=2&to=3**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the select that is rendering has a name: name='to[]'

Comment: This doesn't work. It already can send multiple recipients *if you select them*, but I want them to be already selected because they were sent in the params